# What changed in bibtex from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: bibtex, ubuntu, rubber

I have a small project which uses \bibliographystyle{vancouver}
I'm **not using actual Linux** but the windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem.

On my desktop with Ubuntu 14 I just build it by: rubber file.tex

```
compiling file.tex...
running BibTeX on file...
compiling file.tex...
compiling file.tex...
```

On my laptop with Ubuntu 16 I get:

```
Source path uses special characters, error tracking might get confused.
[biblio] cannot find bibliography style vancouver
compiling file.tex...
running: bibTeX file.aux...
compiling file.tex...
running: bibTeX file.aux...
compiling file.tex...
```

What has changed here?

Even rubber --clean file.tex gives me:

```
Source path uses special characters, error tracking might get confused.
[biblio] cannot find bibliography style vancouver
```

edit:
Latex distro is installed directly from ubuntu by apt-get.
I have same packages installed to both computers, including texlive-publishers

Comment: Exactly which LaTeX installation are you using on Linux? Is is from the Linux dist? If so you probably forgot to install `texlive-publishers` (found via `apt-file search vancouver.bst`)

Comment: Not having run WSL I may be wrong but if paths are being translated between underlying systems I would be checking the obvious part of error message. what do respective paths look like e.g. in Linux are any windows paths changed to odd (special) characters avoid any usual trip hazards such as spaces accents punctuation .\ etc